# What is the Gibbs Free Energy in Zinc Electroplating?

Tags: electrochemistry, electroplating

In zinc electroplating process, where zinc metal (anode) is deposited on an iron plate (cathode), there is no net equation. Then why do we need to apply voltage to the system to produce zinc metal on iron? Does Gibbs Free Energy change, regardless of how much voltage is applied, after electrolysis?